# Converting date and/or time from character string Conversion failed

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @orderwhere varchar(5000)
declare @Pdate DateTime

set @orderwhere = 'Product.ProductID = 1 And Product.ProductDate=' + @Pdate

exec('select Product.ProductID
      from Product
      where ' + @orderwhere)
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Don't edit the question in a way that makes already given answers look stupid. If you have solved one problem and have another instead ask a new question and probably delete the old one.

Comment: Agreed with @stickybit here. The edit is completely different from the original question and can cause unnecessary downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Note: This answer refers to the original question which had a line `DECLARE @Pdate DATETIME = '1001-01-01'` and the error message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." in it.

---

From the manual for [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Date range[:] January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

So your year is definitely to early for a `datetime`.

You can try to use either a [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which ranges from 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31 or just a [`date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with the same range as `datetime2` (regarding the date part, not the time part of course).

Comment: They edited the question with a different error, thought his answers the original posted error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `@Pdate` to varchar for the string concatenation.

```
set @orderwhere = 'Product.ProductID = 1 And Product.ProductDate= '''+ cast(@Pdate as varchar) + ''''
```

Otherwise, it's treated as an addition operation. You'll also need to add in the extra apostrophe's, otherwise your execution fail. This is why it's always good to `PRINT` the statement for debugging before you execute.

Example:

```
declare @orderwhere varchar(5000)
declare @Pdate date = '20160101'

set @orderwhere = 'Product.ProductID = 1 And Product.ProductDate= ''' + cast(@Pdate as varchar) + ''''

print('select Product.ProductID
from Product
where ' + @orderwhere)
```

Or, using a `datetime`

```
declare @orderwhere varchar(5000)
declare @Pdate datetime = '20160101'

set @orderwhere = 'Product.ProductID = 1 And Product.ProductDate= ''' + convert(varchar,@Pdate,120) + ''''

print('select Product.ProductID
from Product
where ' + @orderwhere)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your @pdate to varchar

```
declare @orderwhere varchar(5000)
declare @Pdate DateTime 
declare @Pdatec varchar(50)
set @Pdatec = CAST(@Pdate as varchar(50))


set @orderwhere = 'Product.ProductID = 1 And Product.ProductDate= '''+ @Pdatec + ''''

exec('select Product.ProductID
from Product
where ' + @orderwhere)
```

and add quotation marks.
Try to test your dynamic queries by printing your results.

Comment: scsimon, the fix should work.  The answer is creating a NEW variable (@Pdatec) and converting the date to a varchar.